# Flatten C# Project Files with Build Action of 'Content'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

Is it possible, through Visual Studio, to flatten Files with a Build Action of 'Content'?

Currently if I have the content in a folder then the folder is created. I need the file to be moved up to the root directory on build. Is the only way an xcopy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup.  I think that's unfortunately the case.

You could create a link to the content under the main project instead of actually adding the content to the project.  But, this adds congestion to the main project folder.  Would that work for you?

Comment: Agreed.  That's always bugged me.